# Unitgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_3[X]/(N)$ with $N=1+X^2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, polynomials, ring-theory

What is the unitgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_3[X]/(N)$ with $N=1+X^2$ ?

[From this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2551300/quotient-group-members-mathbbz-3x-n-with-n-1x2), I know that

> ... it is $2X^3+2X+1=2X(X^2+1)+1$, hence $[2X^3+2X+1]=[1]$.

So is it correct that the unitgroup consists of all polynomials, that belong to $[1]$ and $[2]$ ?

(Since $1^2 = 1$ and $2^2=1$  in $\mathbb{Z}_3$.)

Comment: $x^2+1$ is irreducible over $\mathbb{Z}_3$. Hence the quotient is a field, which is the field with $9$ elements.

Comment: No, I think you need to go back and review the definition of a quotient ring before you'd really understand the answer. Note that no polynomial actually becomes $1$ if multiplied by $1+X^2$ as the degree of the product would be at least $2$.

Comment: Think of this as the set of all linear combinations $a+b\gamma$, where $\gamma$ solves $\gamma^2+1 = 0\mod 3$. So you want to see for what values of $a,b$ does $1/(a+b\gamma)$ make sense (i.e. for what values of $a,b$ you can find $c,d$ such that $(a+b\gamma)(c+d\gamma)=1$)

Comment: @JohnBrevik: I've updated the question.

Comment: I'm still not quite with you, but for example the image of $X$ (let's call it $\bar X$) in this quotient is a unit, since $\bar X\cdot 2\bar X = 2\bar X^2 = -\bar X^2 = 1$ (because $\bar X^2=-1$).

Comment: Ah, it seems this is exactly what our prof. wanted us to prove: Is $x$ in $\mathbb{Z}_3/(N)$ a generator for the unitgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_3/(N)$? I asked these questions here first, because the term *unitgroup* or *quotient group* was/is unknown to me.

Comment: Anyway, I still don't get it. Why is $\bar X^2=-1$ ?For every $\bar X$ in $\mathbb{Z}_3$ $\bar X^2$ is never $-1$.