# Quotient group members $\mathbb{Z}_3[X]/N$ with $N=1+X^2$

Tags: discrete-mathematics, normal-subgroups, quotient-group

What are the members of the quotient group $\mathbb{Z}_3[X]/N$ with $N=1+X^2$?

I do not know how to write this out. Which [operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_(mathematics)) do you use? 
Are these all possible polynomials in $\mathbb{Z}_3[X]$ multiplied or added with $N$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You take a polynomial $f\in\mathbb{Z}_3[X]$ and divide it with remainder by $X^2+1$. The remainder is your result.

For example: $2X^3+2X+1\in\mathbb{Z}_3[X]$, then $(2X^3+2X+1)\div (X^2+1)= 2X~~ R~~ 1$ (R stands here for remainder)

It is $2X^3+2X+1=2X(X^2+1)+1$, hence $[2X^3+2X+1]=[1]$.

Comment: And so I can map each possible polynomial to a "remainder-class"? For example $(x^4 + x^2) \div (x^2+1) = x^2 ~~ R~~ 0$, hence $[x^4+x^2] = [0]$. Correct?

Comment: Yes, this is correct.